# Is it true that $\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{o(1)}{t} = o(\ln T)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

The title basically says it all. Here $o(h(t))$ denotes a quantity $f(t)$ such that $f/h \to 0 $ as $t \to \infty$.

I think this should be true, but I'm not entirely sure, and would like some feedback. My progress thus far:

Let $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. Then for any $\epsilon >0 $ we have an $N$ such that $|f(t)|< \epsilon$ for all $t> N$.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{f(t)}{t} &= \sum_{t=1}^N \frac{f(t)}{t} + \sum_{t=N+1}^T\frac{f(t)}{t} \\
&\sim C_N + \epsilon \ln T. 
\end{align*}
Dividing by $\ln T$ one obtains
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{f(t)}{t} \Big/\ln T \sim \epsilon
\end{align*}
but since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, the limit must be $0$.

Does this hold up in court? I'm feeling a bit iffy about it for some reason.

Comment: isn't it $o(1)=f(T)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the small and large $t$
$$\sum_{t \le T} \frac{o(1)}{t} =O(1)\sum_{t \le \log T} \frac{1}{t}+o(1)\sum_{\log  T< t \le T} \frac{1}{t}$$ $$= O(\log \log T)+o(\log T-\log \log T)=o(\log T)$$